# How can I have ruby logger log for each line of execution?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, gherkin

I am very new to ruby, just started learning for doing a automation with cucumber and Gherkin. 
I wanted to capture the each and every action into the logs!!!

Is there a way to capture!!! Thanks for your advice in advance!!!

Thanks 
Ashok Natarajan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to log things in cucumber is using simple puts statements. if you don't want it to show up in the reports you could use kernel.puts

I have also used pry for real time debugging like this: 
http://www.alanmacdougall.com/blog/2012/06/08/interactive-debugging-with-pry/

You must also remember to gather any output from gems that you are using. For example if you use the sequel gem you will probably want to log the database statements. you could use something like

```
require 'logger'
DB.loggers << Logger.new($stdout)
```

Answer (score 3):

If your question is about cucumber logging, check out the man page for available options. Try:

```
cucumber -v -b -x
```

> -b, --backtrace                  Show full backtrace for all errors.
>
> -v, --verbose                    Show the files and features loaded.
>
> -x, --expand                     Expand Scenario Outline Tables in output.