# how to get the logger info of every step in cucumber?

Tags: ruby, cucumber, capybara

I'm using Cucumber to test a web application. and I use `AfterStep` hook to capture the screenshot in every step. it works well and I love it.but there are two problems:

1、 When a step is failed, `AfterStep` can't work, so no screenshot will be captured, and I really really want to get a failed step's screenshot. you may say that Capybara screenshot can capture a failed screenshot. yeah, it is useful, but I want to rename the screenshot and get screenshot of every step even it is passed.

2、I have no idea about using `AfterStep` to get every step's logger info no matter it's failed or passed.

I googled and tried some solutions such as  [Cucumber does not go to AfterStep if the step is failed!](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-ruby/issues/1026)

, [How can I have ruby logger log for each line of execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146107/how-can-i-have-ruby-logger-log-for-each-line-of-execution)

but all failed. Does anyone have any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I have solved the first problem by using test_step_finished event to replace  afterstep.

Comment: I solved the second problem.

Comment: how did you solve the second problem?

Comment: actually, still using test_step_finished event. check this https://luciaca.cn/2018/01/12/how-to-get-logger-info-of-every-step-in-cucumber/ for more details. hope the chinese words doesn't make you more confused.